# Dell Inspiron Wifi off

Tags: wireless, dell, inspiron

I installed a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 and this is my first Ubuntu install. I have a Dell Inspiron 6400 and my wifi is turned off and cant seem to switch it on. I searched a lot on it but can only find answers for Ubuntu 12.04 :( can someone help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and this was printed:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

The main problem was that I didn't check the "Install third party stuff" when my Ubuntu was installing. So I ran the following command:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Went to Additional Drivers tab and checked to use any proprietary driver I want.

Source: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/to-do-list-after-new-installation-of.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and this is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Source: http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.com/2012/07/broadcom-wireless-fix-for-ubuntu-1210.html

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ubuntu world. question you asked has a broader concept, i may require few answers from you :

1. have you checked id your WIFI LED is glowing (or some other mechanism that lets you know that your WIFI is on).
2. reply with what you see as a result of **iwconfig** on commandline.

Meanwhile you can try :

- Disable the non supported driver.
- Go to Synaptic and install b43-fwcutter and firmware-b43-installer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PLUG IN ETHERNET CABLE

run these commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

THEN UNPLUG ETHERNET AND REBOOT