# Problem connecting to internet

Tags: networking

Hey guys I JUST got ubuntu 12.10 and I have no idea how to use it. I can't get my wifi to work. I click on the wifi-ish signal on the top right corner but it doesn't show anything about a wifi connection. I HAVE enabled networking. The button to switch on my wifi doesn't do anything. I probably don't have the right driver, but if so, how do I download it? And which one?

Comment: open a terminal and enter the following command one by one and   edit your question to post result of `lspci`, `sudo lshw -c network`, `rfkill list all` and `lsmod`

Comment: yes, as Web-E said, more information is needed to diagnose this issue.  Your problem may be related to [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210874/dell-inspiron-wifi-off), but it may not, depending on your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy wireless drivers for it, that's what I did. It cost me £8 and I just plugged it into my computer and then the wireless worked.